# How to do load testing of SNS-->SQS-->LAMBDA

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, load-testing, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a solution

```
SNS-->SQS-->LAMBDA-->ES(ElastciSearch)
```

I want to test this with heavy load like 10K or 5K  request to SNS per second.
The size of the test record can be very small (1kb) and any type of json record .

Is there anyway to test this load ?I did find anything which is native to AWS for this test .

Answer (score 1):

You could try with jmeter. JMeter has support for testing JMS interfaces for messaging systems. You can use the AWS Java SDK to get a SNS JMS interface

Answer (score 0):

Agree, you can use JMeter to execute load testing over SNS. Create Java Request sampler class using AWS SDK library to publish messages in SNS topic, build a jar and install it under lib/ext.

https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/awsmeter

In this repository you cand find Java Request sampler classes created to publish messages in Standard Topic or FIFO Topic, depends of the kind of Topic you need use other message properties like deduplication id or group id for FIFO topic.

Here you can find details to subscribe SQS queue to SNS topic.